# Grounding problem

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

When I ground my panel to an 8ft grounding rod the lights flicker almost like half power kind of thing but when I ground the panel to my water pipes everything works normal what would be causing this problem

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Your grounding shouldn't affect the power unless something else is wrong; would you give us more info? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I’m from Philadelphia and im finishing the basement in my home switching from metal to pvc pipes , new cement , etc . So when I was switching the pipes I noticed the lights were flickering never lost power completely the lights will get real dim flicker twice and go back to normal that’ll keep happening like every two seconds so I ground my panel box to the main water pipe . So I knew my metal rod which surprising is under the breaker box was bad and faulty so I had someone install a new one when I switched the ground to the rod The power was acting the same way it was before

Comment: I’m not really good at explaining things maybe pictures would be a better explanation

Comment: The main point Daniel is making is that ground is for safety only.  None of the electric devices in the house should use or be affected by grounding because ground doesn't carry a current... unless something is wrong.

Comment: I would get yourself an electrician before you kill yourself.

Answer (score 4):

### Call the power company and report an outage

This is a "lost neutral".   The power company needs to come out and fix your neutral connection, and they should do this for free and treat it like an outage.

In the meantime turn off your main breaker.

I suspect your neutral wire has been broken for quite some time.  What's been happening, so far, is that neutral current has leapt from your neutral bus, through your neutral-ground bond, through your grounding electrode system, through the metal water pipes connecting to your neighbors, through *their* grounding electrodes, through *their* neutral-ground bond, to their neutral service wire.   This is bad.

When you messed with your grounding electrode, you uncovered the problem.

The power company should fix it for free.  It's probably up at the pole.